# Prolog Sorting List By Rule Position

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog and for the following program:

```
place(Store,2,a).
place(Store,1,b).
place(Store,3,d).
place(Store,4,c).
placeSort(S,List):- findall(L,place(S,N,L),List).
```

output: `List = [a, b, d, c].`

By using placeSort(S,List) , I can find all the elements(a,b,c,d) that contains S (Store).

However what I want to achieve here is to sort the Position of a,b,c,d by using N, however I dont know how to do so as using sort will just sort it out by alphabetical order

```
placeSort(S,NewList):- findall(L,place(S,N,L),List),sort(List,NewList).
```

output: `List = [a, b, c, d].`

what I want to achieve : `List = [b,a,d,c]`

**I know by using `placeSort(S,NewList):- findall([N,L],place(S,N,L),List),sort(List,NewList).`

it will return a list of lists sorted by numbers.
output : `List = [[1, b], [2, a], [3, d], [4, c]].`

but im not sure how to take away the numbers and just take the alphabets instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: define a predicate `only_letters([[1, b], [2, a], ...], [b, a, ...]).` so that you can call it as `only_letters(List, Result).` and have in `Result` the output you desire.

Comment: or without defining an `only_letters/2` predicate, since `nth0(1, [X, Y], Y)` already does what you want on an item of that list, you  could simply do: `findall([X,Y], place(_,X,Y), List), sort(List, SortedList), maplist(nth0(1), SortedList, Result).`

Answer (score 1):

SWI-Prolog offers the interesting builtin [order_by](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=order_by/2)/2, filling the gap traditional Prolog suffers when compared to SQL, with library([solutionsequences](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=solutionsequences)):

```
?- order_by([asc(X)],place(P,X,W)).
X = 1,
W = b ;
X = 2,
W = a ;
...
```

So you can avoid full list construction.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use `setof/3` (which sorts by term) and pick a term form that works for you on your sort. In this case, you can collect terms of the form `N-X` where they satisfy, `place(_, N, X)`:

```
setof(N-X, place(S,N,X), OrderedList).  % Assuming `S` is bound
```

This will result in:

```
OrderedList = [1-b, 2-a, 3-d, 4-c]
```

Then you can use `maplist/3` to get your list by defining a simple mapping:

```
foo(_-X, X).
maplist(foo, OrderedList, List).
```

This will then give you just the elements you want.

Your complete predicate would look like:

```
foo(_-X, X).

placeSort(S, List) :-
    setof(N-X, place(S,N,X), OrderedList),
    maplist(foo, OrderedList, List).
```

Obviously, you'd choose sensible names for your facts, predicates, and variables. My names (`foo`, `List`, `OrderedList`, `S`, `N`, `X`) are not sufficient, in my opinion, for an application but I am not familiar with your actual problem domain, so this is just for illustration purposes.

As an aside, note that in your facts `Store` is a variable, so that's not particularly meaningful in the facts. I kept your use of `S` in your predicate, but it's unclear to me how you really intend to use it.